# Configure webpack to generate separate vendor js files for each entry

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have multiple js apps in one application. Each js app has different dependency on js libraries and each js app is an `entry` for webpack. Current webpack setting is generating just one `vendor.bundle.js`.

How can I configure webpack to generate separate vendor bundle js files for each entry?

Expecting Output:

- vendor.bundle.js
- vendor~app1.bundle.js
- vendor~app2.bundle.js
- app1.bundle.js
- app2.bundle.js

**webpack config**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
     'app1': './src/AppOne.js',
     'app2': './src/AppTwo.js'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './resources/js/dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },

    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                commons: {
                    name: 'vendor',
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    minChunks: 2
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read into https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/ configuration?
Also notice that some of parameters in configuration can be functions inside which you can do some more advanced stuff

Comment: @Xesenix Yes, I did. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `optimization` block

or

Using `chunks: 'all'` seem to work.

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all'
        }
},
```